# How to manipulate the & special character in shell

Tags: bash, shell, cut

I want to manipulate URLs in a shell script. I need to cut the URL with the `&` delimiter, and get the corresponding string.

I tried `example="$(cut -d'&' -f2- <<< $1)"` but when I'm executing this code and trying to `echo $example`, it wants to execute the `$example` content.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: `echo "$example"` quote it with double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not.

When you do:

```
example="$(cut -d'&' -f2- <<< $1)"
```

it tries to execute the `cut`. As a test:

```
ljm@verlaine[~]$ a='1&ls&3&4'
ljm@verlaine[~]$ example="$(cut -d'&' -f2- <<< $a)"
ljm@verlaine[~]$ echo $example
ls&3&4
ljm@verlaine[~]$
```

And, although quoting like iBug suggested is a good idea and best practice, it is not absolutely required here.

Answer (score 2):

You probably just need to quote the variables.

Problem script:

```
#!/bin/bash
example="$(cut -d'&' -f2- <<< $1)"
echo $example
```

If you run it through [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), you get this in the output:

```
example="$(cut -d'&' -f2- <<< $1)"
                              ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
echo $example
     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

Fixed script:

```
#!/bin/bash
example="$(cut -d'&' -f2- <<< "$1")"
echo "$example"
```